# Installing numba on windows for python

Tags: python, pip, numba

I am trying to install numba via pip for use with an API in python but I am getting the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> py -m pip install numba
Collecting numba
  Using cached numba-0.58.1.tar.gz (2.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nljmbau3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nljmbau3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nljmbau3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\aiden\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nljmbau3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 51, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in _guard_py_ver
      RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Does numba not support the latest python version or is there a way around this ?

I tried to install using `pip install numba` but cannot get past that error.

Comment: The error clearly states `Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported.` So use version of Python lower than 3.12

Comment: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/9197

Answer (score 2):

According to your stack trace, `RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.12.0; only versions >=3.8,<3.12 are supported.`This means you can only install it on python versions 3.8 - 3.11 as at this time. One way to do this is by virtual environments. You can create a virtual environment using a version of Python between 3.8 and 3.11 and then install numba in that virtual environment. See more about virtual environments [here.](https://medium.com/co-learning-lounge/create-virtual-environment-python-windows-2021-d947c3a3ca78)